# What softwares should we use in creating a live web-based dashboard?

Tags: javascript, php, vba

We're new programmers in the company and our supervisor wants us to make a web-based dashboard that updates every time.

But there are even no senior programmer here that helps us and trained us because our supervisor is a technical sales director.

Their sales department uses excel file, and we've just used macro vb and link the charts to a powerpoint presentation, but our supervisor does't want that kind of dashboard we present.

Is it possible to make a live web-based dashboard coming from their excel file?

We know the fundamentals and basics of some programming languages like php,html,css,javascript, java,c,c++,c#,vb. And IDE such as VSCode,Visual Basic, notepad++,etc.

What will be your recommendation for us? May I know what softwares should we use, download, and learn?

Comment: Don't panic. There are many, many, many free dashboards, also called report generators, especially web based. Search around, or wait for an answer here. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above issues sound like they can be resolved with using Power BI. Power BI has come a long way and can now be embedded in PowerPoint files, plus you can view real time dashboards online via its web-based service (app.powerbi.com).

Speaking from a professional perspective, I have 5+ years of experience in the field of analysis/reporting and have so far tried 2 options for local (offline) or web based dashboards.

The first is Power BI through which you can connect the Excel dataset, create the visualisations, publish the graphs report to its dedicated server (need Pro or Enterprise Premium license to do that) and create a web-based dashboard. The web based dashboard can be schedule refreshed every day at a specific time of your liking.

The second option involves Python programming, one of its web-based frameworks called Flask and a graphs library called Matplotlib. Through Flask you should be able to generate a webpage which you can host on your company's server. Through Python's IDLE GUI, you can write a script which transforms your Excel dataset to match the columns you just want for the graphs. Through Matplotlib, you should be able to generate the graphs and add them on your Flask generated webpage.

I'm hoping these options will meet the expectations of your dashboard project

Comment: yes, we've research about this power BI. We hope our supervisor agreed to this software because it is very powerful especially when it comes to data visualizations. Thank you very much sir. We'll try the second option as well and do some research about that.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm happy to assist further should there be any future concerns on that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use visualize javascript plugin such as **AMCharts.js**, **D3.js**, **Chartjs** to visualize your data but you need to have codding skills using javascript and use such libraries give you enough flexibility of choosing your chart that you want based on the business need, before that you should prepare solid part of code for reading the excel file then visualize the imported data .
:
check below links:

1- [AM charts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/):

2-[D3.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

3- [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

4- [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5) may help you how to import the excel data using js.